# MySQL query in Wordpress with AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, mysql, wpdb

I have a search  form which searches the DB and returns back some data. I have managed to use Wordpress wpdb to connect and use select statement on the table and retrieve data. Everything works fine..But..I have page refresh issue. I want to add AJAX code in order to get my data without refreshing. So, I have followed along with [this](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/tutorial-ajax-wordpress/), [this](http://bordoni.me/ajax-wordpress/#comments) and tutorials. But,I'm facing some problems with them. So, here's what I got:

My JS code:

```
var j$ = jQuery;
var search_text = j$(".cv__text").val();
j$.post({
    url: "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>",
    data: ({
        action: "search_cv", search_text: search_text
    }),
    success: function (response){
        console.log(response);
        j$("#search_results").html(response);
    }
});
```

My functions.php:

```
function search_cv(){
    $search_text = ucfirst($_POST["search_text"]);

    //Creating New DB Connection

    $database_name = "employee_cv";

    $mydb = new wpdb(DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, $database_name, DB_HOST);
    $mydb -> show_errors();

    if ($_POST["search_text"] != null){

        $result = $mydb -> get_results(
            $mydb -> prepare(
                'SELECT * FROM employee 
                WHERE Experience = %s',
                $search_text
            ) );

    }

    foreach ($result as $employee){
        //Here I just echo html blocks (divs, paragraphs etc.)                          
    }

    die();
}

add_action( 'wp_ajax_search_cv', 'search_cv' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_search_cv', 'search_cv' );
```

My HTML:

```
<form class="searchCV_form" role="form" action="">
    <div>
        <input type="text" id="search_text" name="search_text" class="cv__text">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-primary cv__button search--form-btn">SUBMIT</button>
        </span>
    </div>
</form>
<div id="search_results"></div>
```

So, after all this changes, I still get the refresh on page and also, my query is not working at all. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. I've used AJAX before on my projects but never with Wordpress and php.

**EDIT**

Apparently either I'm doing something wrong or the question is wrong. Can someone just point me on how to use AJAX with wpdb requests to MySQL? On own experience? preferably with some details? all the tutorials i found seems to fail me here.

Comment: Where is your "JS code"? What file?

Comment: @s_ha_dum my JS code is in a separate javascript file. It has some additional codes in it as well, and everything is working. I've enqued the script via functions.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would need to see your trigger function but it sounds like you just need to add [event.preventdefault](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) to the [submit](https://api.jquery.com/submit/). This will block the page load while still executing AJAX.

```
$("form.searchCV_form").submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    alert( "We're not going anywhere now..." );
    // j$.post...
});
```

or

```
$("form.searchCV_form").submit(function(e){
    alert( "We're not going anywhere now..." );
    // j$.post...

    return false;
});
```

More info at [event.preventDefault() vs. return false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/event-preventdefault-vs-return-false).

Here are some mods to get it working how you expected -- sans actual searching.

FORM

```
<form class="searchCV_form" role="form" action="">
     <div>
         <input type="text" id="search_text" name="search_text" class="cv__text">
         <span class="input-group-btn">
             <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-primary cv__button search--form-btn">SUBMIT</button>
         </span>
     </div>
 </form>
 <div id="search_results"></div>
```

JQUERY

```
<script>
// wrap everything in a closure
(function($){

  // get our references
  var $form = $('form.searchCV_form'),
      $search_field = $('#search_text'),
      $results = $('#search_results');

  // AJAX search call
  function do_search() {

    // grab the query value from the search field
    var search_text = $search_field.val();

    // do a POST ajax call
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>',
      data: ({
        action: "search_cv",
        search_text: search_text
      }),
      success: function (response){
        console.log(response);
        $results.html(response);
      }
    });
  }

  // on submit, do the search but return false to stop page refresh
  $form.submit(function(e) {
    do_search();
    return false;
  });

})(jQuery);
</script>
```

WP AJAX

```
function search_cv()
{
    // get the search query
    $search_text = ucfirst($_POST["search_text"]);

    // clean it up
    $search_text = sanitize_text_field( $search_text);

    // ... do stuff with it

    // output the HTML which will be consumed by $.html()
    ?><div>You searched for <?php echo $search_text; ?> and we found... </div><?php

    // stop doing stuff
    die();
}

add_action( 'wp_ajax_search_cv', 'search_cv' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_search_cv', 'search_cv' );
```

Comment: No, I don't think that's what I need. Because this won't let the back-end code to execute.

Comment: The AJAX call is `j$.post` which triggers the backend and returns the outcome. You don't need to leave the page at all.

Comment: that's the problem.. apparently nothing is returned as an outcome. Once I click submit, page is refreshed and url becomes: **http://myurl/pageName/?search_text=value**

Comment: can you please follow the links I posted above? I've used those codes. And, in one of the links, the AJAX is used exactly as I've posted above. I'm completely stuck now..

Comment: Was this helpful? Seems like a full AJAX solution, you just need to replace the `do stuff with it` with your own DB calls and output some HTML. But it's working perfectly on my end.

Comment: why to wrap everything in a closure?

Comment: I've readjusted the code and it worked. from 3rd attempt. Thanks..

Comment: You're welcome. Did the update help or was there anything specific that did the trick for you?

Comment: Closures are just good form for snippets. It's better to wait for the document to load before adding listeners. If that is too late you can always adjust but you'll have a better idea when the JS will trigger.

Answer (score 0):

Your Javascript file has PHP in it:

```
url: "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>",
```

Javascript files are not parsed by the PHP interpretter, so the URL you providing is literally `<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>`. You need to create a Javascript variable that you can access. What you want to do is this (taken from the [`wp_localize_script()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script) codex page, with modifications:

```
// Register the script
wp_register_script( 'some_handle', 'path/to/myscript.js' );

// Localize the script with new data
$translation_array = array(
    'myajax_url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'),
);
wp_localize_script( 'some_handle', 'object_name', $translation_array );

// Enqueued script with localized data.
wp_enqueue_script( 'some_handle' );
```

Then in your Javascript:

```
url: some_handle.myajax_url,
```

Comment: I'm also digging right now on that direction, but apparently, some tutorials used the above statement in js file. I also thought that it won't parse, but wasn't sure there..let me try this out then

Comment: You can force the server to parse `.js` files but even then, loading the page out of WordPress context would mean the Core functions are not available. It still wouldn't work.

Comment: I've changed the code to absolute url. But it still won't work

Comment: Please describe "won't work". Exactly where does it fail?

Comment: I'm not sure where does it all fail. But everything I've tried doesn't make any difference. i still get the refresh and no result from sql query.

Comment: Then you need to do some debugging on your end. You've got several answers already. We cannot simply guess our way to the right one. I know that this answer addresses at least one problem as I am sure that PHP is not processed in a Javascript file.

Comment: I know that. Thanks for your patience. I'm debugging the best way I can right now. I'm not a guru:) I don't think that url is a problem anymore here.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Register the script - located in functions.php (usually)
wp_register_script( 'some_handle', 'path/to/myscript.js' );

//In the file you need the ajax results

// Enqueued script
wp_enqueue_script( 'some_handle' );

// Localize the script with new data
wp_localize_script( 'some_handle', 'object_name', array('ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) );

// the ajax call in the js file
jQuery.ajax({
    url : object_name.ajax_url,
    type : 'post',
    data : {
           action:'search_cv', 
           search_text: search_text
    }
    success : function( response ) {
         response = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
         //use the response variable to print what you need on the webpage. Basically instead of running the foreach in the php function run it here with js
   }
 });
```

In the php function (which should be in functions.php) remove the foreach and just echo the result

```
echo json_encode($results);
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate your answer?

Comment: Is it clearer now?

Comment: Yeap..thanks..I'll give it a shot. Fingers crossed:)